# In Objective-C How Do I Increase a Number Displayed by UILabel Gradually?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

Say I want to increase a number displayed by UILabel from 0%

```
UILabel *percentage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %ld%%", 0];
```

to 50% in 2 seconds.

```
percentage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %ld%%", 0]
```

Here is what I tried to use NSTimer:

```
self.percent = 0;
self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.04
                                     target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(updateLabel) 
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

//updateLabel
- (void)updateLabel{
    self.percentage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %ld%%", self.percent++];
    if (self.percent > 50) {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }
}
```

But the UI looks very jerky, not smooth at all looks like all the changes are stacked and will apply sometimes but not sure when, and its taking definitely longer than 2 seconds. Is this because that 0.04 sec is too short?

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the cause of your problem or not...

Don't append the new time to your label text each time; each time the timer fires set the label to your new value:

```
self.percentage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld%%", 
  self.percent++]
```

Comment: sorry fixed that but thats not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the time interval in timer, then you get smooth execution:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.0001
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(updateLabel)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
```